# PrincipalContext sending windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to use the code below but instead of username and password send the windows authentication (User.Identity.Name) so only users with the correct domain admin rights can run this in the controller?

```
    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain.local", "username", "password");
```

Comment: What is stopping you from replacing `"username"` with `User.Identity.Name` in your code?  That's what you're doing in [your previous question on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56878145/asp-net-ad-group-check-variable).  So what's the issue?

Comment: When I try that it (take out the password and change the user) says: An invalid dn syntax has been specified. - I am assuming it wants that password.

Comment: Well, yes, it needs a password for that user.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you want to limit access to a controller method then use an [Authorize] attribute on the method.